# Chrome Extension Issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension, local-storage, settimeout

Working on some background javascript for my chrome extension, and my test is to have it do something every `x` seconds according to a changing variable. I decided to use setTimeout. I then run it.. and it just spams me with alerts.

http://jsfiddle.net/Ultimate/TpsBv/2/ (Do NOT use the fiddle unless you have something like chrome where you can stop the alerts)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    localStorage.seconds = 5; //Added for testing
    wait();
});
function sayHi() {
    alert(localStorage.seconds);
    wait();
}
function wait() {
    var time = localStorage.seconds * 1000
    setTimeout(sayHi(), time);
}
```

Note: *I made sure to do * 1000 because they're milliseconds, and jQuery IS enabled.*

Comment: You're running `sayHi` *immediately* (that's what `sayHi()` does) and then passing the *return value* of `sayHi` to `setTimeout` (which happens to be `undefined` here). You want to pass the function `sayHi` *itself* to `setTimeout`, not the result of the function: `setTimeout(sayHi, time)`

Comment: Wow, you just reminded me to check the javascript console.

Comment: Thank you, and I fixed it thanks to before you edited it :p

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, fixed when the first comment reminded me to check my chrome console.

Anyway, I found the fix here: [Determining where Maximum call stack size is being exceeded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7474368/determining-where-maximum-call-stack-size-is-being-exceeded)

EDIT: New fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/Ultimate/TpsBv/5/

```
setTimeout(function() { sayHi(); }, time);
```